# How to show an image while hovering on another image in different div

Tags: html, css

My aim is to show the `image Manager-icon.png` in `#watch #background #manager #logo` when hovering the image `blue-pointer.jpg` in `#watch #background #manager #logo`.

My HTML and CSS are shown below:

```
<div id="watch">
<div id="background">
    <img src="image/watch.jpg" height=100%>
    <div id="manager">
        <div id="pointer">
            <a href="login.html">
                <img src="Image/blue-pointer.jpg" width=100%>
            </a>
        </div>              
        <div id="logo">
            <img src="Image/Manager-icon.png" width=100%>           
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
#watch #background #manager #pointer{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 28%;
    top: 79%;
}
#watch #background #manager #pointer img:hover + #watch #background #manager #logo img{
    display: inline;
}

#watch #background #manager #logo{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top:35%;
}

#watch #background #manager #logo img{
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`+` sign refers to the siblings so, since `#pointer img` is not even close to a sibling to `#logo img`, nothing happens. Assuming that the only contents of the `#pointer a` is the image and the only contents of the `#pointer` is the anchor, you can do your CSS like this:

```css
#pointer:hover + #logo img {
    display: inline;
}
```

Notice one thing: You don't need to write this whole chain of ids. `ID` must be unique in the whole webpage so refering to it in the CSS is enough. You don't have to write this

```css
#watch #background #manager #pointer {
    ...
}
```

This is **completely enough**

```css
#pointer {
    ...
}
```

Comment: which means i can fix it by chnaging
#watch #background #manager #pointer img:hover + #watch #background #manager #logo img to
#watch #background #manager #pointer :hover + #watch #background #manager #logo img

Comment: Not exactly. Change this: `#watch #background #manager #pointer img:hover + #watch #background #manager #logo img` to this: `#pointer:hover + #logo img`.

Comment: Well, they should be. It is **forbidden** to use more than one element with the same `id`.

Comment: I hv 3 more#watch #background #xxx #pointer and#watch #background #xxx #logo in my code. is it possible to keep the structure ?

Comment: No! You can have **only one** element with the `id` attribute of the specific value. Change the `id`s to e.g. class names.